# Unifying links for google searches

Tags: google, google-search-console, canonical-url

What method do you recommend me using, to tell Google that links like:

1. www.site.com/**en**/aslgm
2. www.site.com/**ro**/aslgm
3. www.site.com/**es**/aslgm
4. www.site.com/**...** /**...**

It's the same as www.site.com/aslgm ?

I already use `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.site.com/aslgm" />`

Comment: Are they actually the same pages? The URLs imply they are different languages.

Comment: The language parameter is not actually necessary because if it's not there it loads the language id that's in the session or the browser language. The content in the same, only the menus and some text changes

Comment: It's like on YouTube, you change the language... but the video is still the same. Only YouTube's context changes, but not the video's description, language, tags or anything else

Comment: Why have the parameter in the first place then? You can just have an option that sets the language and redirects back to the normal page.

Comment: good point, and I'm thinking of doing that in the future... but I stil need to study more about it, because even YouTube has a parameter that's been added whith the language (except for English I think)

Comment: True, but YouTube doesn't need to do any SEO since they are owned by Google. They know the correct URLs for the videos, and know how popular each of them are without needing to look at things like how many links point to them.

Comment: true indeed, as I said... I still have to study different cases and see which suites better. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

Using `rel="canonical"` on those pages (as you have done) is sufficient.

See: [Google Webmaster Tools - About rel="canonical"](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)

Comment: Well either it takes time to fix all those "duplicates" on searcing site.com on google, either it ain't enough

Comment: If those pages have already been indexed without the canonical link then yes it is going to take time for Google to recrawl these pages and reindex your site. This also depends on the crawl rate of your site. How long has it been? The only other possibility would be to remove these other pages from the Google index (either a manual URL request, or via robots) - but that is also going to take time and should be unnecessary and importantly will run the risk of this page not being indexed at all.

Comment: Well, the indexing rate it's the default one (google's decision) and I think things starts to change because I see less results for `site:site.com` but more consistency (better rank, better positioning ...)